# Coding a guessing game in Jython Environment for Students ( JES )

Tags: if-statement, computer-science, jes

**I am trying to code a guessing game in JES using the pseudo code below:**

Generate a random  single digit number

Have the user guess the number

If the user does not guess correctly give them a clue – indicate whether the number is even or odd and ask the user to guess again.

If the user does not guess correctly,  give another clue – indicate whether the number is a multiple of 3 and ask the user to guess again.

If the user does not guess correctly, give another clue – indicate whether the number is less than or greater than 5 and ask the user to guess again.

If the user does not guess correctly,
display a box indicating the correct answer and the number of guesses the user made.

If the user has guessed correctly, display a box indicating their guess is correct and how many guesses were required

Show the amount of time the user played the guessing game.

**There are so many conditions I have no clue how to have the program ask each question, analyze the answer, and if the condition isn't met, to move on to the next one. When I run this code, it is just stuck in the loop of asking the user to guess and does not move through the if statements to give the user hints if they are incorrect.**

**Below is my current code which obviously is incorrect. I am also aware there may be indenting issues in this post.**

```
from random import *
from time import *

def main():
  a= randrange( 0, 11 ) 
  start= clock()
  numberOfGuesses= 0 
  userGuess= requestInteger( " Please guess a single digit number " ) 

  while userGuess != a:
    userGuess= requestInteger( " Please guess a single digit number " ) 
    if userGuess % 2 == 0:
      showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number is          even " ) 
    if userGuess % 2 != 0:
      showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number is odd " ) 
    if userGuess % 3 != 0:
      showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number is not a multiple of 3 " )
    if userGuess > 5:
      showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number is greater than 5 " ) 
    if userGuess < 5:
      showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number is greater than 5 " ) 
    else:
      showInformation( " Correct " )
```

**REVISED AND WORKING CODE**

```
from random import*
from time import*

def main ():
  a= randrange( 0, 10 )
  start= clock()
  numberOfGuesses= 0
  userGuess= requestNumber( " Please guess a single digit number " )
  end= clock()
  elapsedTime= end - start

  if userGuess != a and userGuess % 2 == 0:
    showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number is even " )
    userGuess= requestNumber( " Please guess a single digit number " )
    numberOfGuesses= numberOfGuesses + 1
  elif userGuess != a and a % 2 != 0:
      showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number is odd " )
      userGuess= requestNumber( " Please guess a single digit number " )
      numberOfGuesses= numberOfGuesses + 1

  if userGuess != a and a % 3 != 0:
    showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number IS NOT a multiple of 3 " )
    userGuess= requestNumber( " Please guess a single digit number " )
    numberOfGuesses= numberOfGuesses + 1

  if userGuess != a and a > 5:
    showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number is greater than 5 " )
    userGuess= requestNumber( " Please guess a single digit number " )
    numberOfGuesses= numberOfGuesses + 1
  if userGuess != a and a  < 5:
    showInformation( " Incorrect! Please try again. Hint: The number is less than 5 " )
    userGuess= requestNumber( " Please guess a single digit number " )
    numberOfGuesses= numberOfGuesses + 1
  if userGuess == a:
    showInformation( " Correct! " )
    showInformation( " The correct answer was" + " " + str(a) + " It took you " + str(elapsedTime) + " " + " seconds to complete this game " )
  elif userGuess != a :
    showInformation( " Incorrect! " + " " + " The correct answer was" + " " + str(a) + " It took you " + str(elapsedTime) + " " + " seconds to complete this game " )
```

Answer (score 0):

its stuck in the loop because user cant guess the same num that randnum genertes
"while userguess !=a  " it'll never be true

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for your answer Ahmad. The correct code, ( Although it may be a bit long) is edited into my question.